# ZipArchive is not working on server php

Tags: php, linux, file, unzip

I am using code for unzip a file on server, but its not working, I want to unzip the zip file myfolder.zip on server. Code which I am using is :

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('myfolder.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('./');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'done!';
} else {
echo 'not done!';
}
?>
```

Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: Is the directory writable by the web server user?

Comment: What is the PHP Version?. Do you have any Errors/Warnings

Comment: yes, directory is writable(777) and PHP Version 5.2.17.

Comment: Is the zip extension built-in/installed in your PHP version (check `phpinfo()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade server php version, ZipArchive will not work with php 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, however Even i had faced a similar issue, increasing the memory limit directive in my `php.ini` fixed the issue for me.

you could find `memory_limit` directive, increase it and restart your web server and try to execute your code.